# How to iterate through all subcollections of size K, in ascending order of their sums.

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, sorting, complexity-theory

Suppose I have a sorted array such as

```
int[] sarr = new int[] { 0, 1, 3, 5 };
```

and I want to iterate through all combinations of size `K` in ascending order of their sum. For example, if `K=2` then the combinations in order are

```
{0, 1} (sum = 1)
{1, 0} (sum = 1)
{0, 3} (sum = 3)
{3, 0} (sum = 3)
{3, 1} (sum = 4)
{1, 3} (sum = 4)
{5, 0} (sum = 5)
.
.
.
```

I want to do this without first getting all combinations because I want to stop as soon as I've found one that satisfies a condition `Func<int[],bool> cond`.

Is there a known way of doing this?

Comment: Just being picky, seeing as `{0, 1}` and `{1, 0}` both show up it looks like you are looking for arrangements rather than combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `yield return` to describe all combinations, arrangements or whatever subcollections you want to generate and then use `FirstOrDefault` on the result.

That way you will only generate all subcollections if there isn't one you are looking for or the one you are looking for is the very last.

On about getting them ascending by the sum of the elements, sort the initial collection and then pick `k` elements from start to end. You can even generate combinations and from these to generate all possible permutations and thus you will get all your arrangements.

A quick way to get all combinations:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var initialArray = new[] { 0, 1, 3, 5 };
        var subArrayLength = 2;

        foreach (var subArray in GetSubArrays(initialArray, subArrayLength))
            Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", subArray)}]");

        Console.WriteLine("Searching for array that contains both 1 and 5.");
        var arrayFulfillingCriteria = GetSubArrays(initialArray, subArrayLength).FirstOrDefault(array => array.Contains(1) && array.Contains(5));
        if (arrayFulfillingCriteria != null)
            Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", arrayFulfillingCriteria)}]");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No array found.");
    }

    static IEnumerable<int[]> GetSubArrays(int[] initialArray, int subArrayLength)
    {
        var indexStack = new Stack<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, subArrayLength));

        do
        {
            var subArray = indexStack.Select(i => initialArray[i]).Reverse().ToArray();
            yield return subArray;

            var index = indexStack.Pop();
            while (indexStack.Count != 0 && indexStack.Count < subArrayLength && index == initialArray.Length - (subArrayLength - indexStack.Count))
                index = indexStack.Pop();

            while (indexStack.Count < subArrayLength && index < initialArray.Length - (subArrayLength - indexStack.Count))
            {
                index++;
                indexStack.Push(index);
            }
        }
        while (indexStack.Count != 0);
    }
}
```

The only reason I can think of where you would need arrangements (seeing as you order by sum) is that the items within the sub array need to be in a particular order.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>> getAllSubsets = null;
getAllSubsets = xs =>
    (xs == null || !xs.Any())
        ? Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<int>>()
        :  xs.Skip(1).Any()
            ? getAllSubsets(xs.Skip(1))
                .SelectMany(ys => new [] { ys, xs.Take(1).Concat(ys) })
            : new [] { Enumerable.Empty<int>(), xs.Take(1) };
```

Now, given this:

```
Func<int[],bool> cond = xs => true;

int[] sarr = new int[] { 0, 1, 3, 5, }; 

var result =
    getAllSubsets(sarr)
        .Where(xs => xs.Count() == 2)
        .Where(xs => cond(xs.ToArray()));
```

I get this as the result:

```
{0, 1} 
{0, 3} 
{1, 3} 
{0, 5} 
{1, 5} 
{3, 5}
```